# How do I get a Java program I installed running?

Tags: java

I downloaded a program implemented in Java (in this case, http://julian.togelius.com/mariocompetition2009/index.php). I first tried opening the Play.class file with Java, but it spit out an error i couldn't see because the console window disappeared so fast. I replicated this on the command line, and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Play/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Play.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Play.class.  Program will exit.
```

What do i have to do to get this to run properly? (If this belongs on Superuser then that's fine.)

Comment: Could you also post the command you're executing in the command prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to invoke the program without the .class

```
java Play
```

instead of

```
java Play.class
```

**EDIT**

Further explanation of the problem

( or whatever the full class name is )

For instance if you have a class defined like this:

```
 package a.b.c.d;

 public class MyClass {
     public void main( String [] args ) {
          System.out.println( "Hey there");
     }
  }
```

You can compile it like this:

```
 javac -D . MyClass.java
```

*The -D . option is used to tell the compiler where to create the package structure. In this case it is "." ( current directory )*

Which will create the following directory structure

```
a\b\c\d\MyClass.class  ( assuming  windows )
```

To run it you use:

```
java a.b.c.d.MyClass // with the full package name and wihtout the .class
```

See [this.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2b)

Answer (score 3):

from the website you linked:

How to participate (it's easy!)
If you plan to participate, you should join the Mario Competition Google Group. **All technical** and organizational questions should be posted to this group, where they will be answered by the organizers and stored in a searchable achive.

But first you will have to develop your controller, using your method of choice and the Java software package. **First of all, look at the getting started page**; more technical information coming soon.

From the getting started page

```
java ch.idsia.scenarios.Play
```

In other words: first start reading on the website then come back here

Comment: Indeed, if you are really lazy all commands are here: 
http://julian.togelius.com/mariocompetition2009/gettingstarted.php

Comment: Just in case, here are the advanced options :P http://julian.togelius.com/mariocompetition2009/advanced.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a path problem. One easy solution is to copy Play.java to the directory in which the java executable resides. A better solution would be to add the path to your java executables in the default system path and call java from the directory containing Play.java

Comment: It's not a path problem - the 'java' command just expects a class name, not a filename. See Oscar Reyes' answer above.

Comment: Putting anything in the directory in which the java executable resides (i.e. the JDK or JRE bin directory) is a bad idea! And note that the source file first needs to be compiled into a class file before you can run the program.